This line in Antiochus Strategos account on The Capture of Jerusalem by the Persians in 614 AD, is theological or historical event?
The following line is from The Capture of Jerusalem by the Persians in 614 AD by Antiochus Strategos

And in the same manner, the walls of Jericho, when it pleased God to
lay them low, were suddenly overthrown; and He, the all good, humbled
also by the Emperor Heraclius the multitude of the Persians, so soon
as He, the clement One, looked with pity on His people

I am not well-read in the history of Christianity, and since the English translation is from 1910, I am unable to find another translation.
F.C. CONYBEARE notes

I have much reduced its bulk by omitting pious ejaculations and other
passages devoid of historical interest

I am unable to understand whether this line is theological or an event, as there is no proper context. Where can I find a full-context
translation?

Wikipedia says that Heraclius likely conquered Jerusalem in 630 CE. Is that what you're asking?

Antiochos Strategos may have been the same person as Antiochus of Palestine but this is unproven.

If you are referring to the collapse of the Walls of Jericho, or a siege that took place at the time and as described in the Bible, then that story is simply propaganda. There is no truth in it. from Wikipedia The Fall of Jericho >According to Joshua 6:1–27, the walls of Jericho fell after the Israelites marched around the city walls [for a week]. Excavations at Tell es-Sultan, the biblical Jericho, have failed to find any traces of a city at the relevant time (end of the Bronze Age), which has led to a consensus among scholars that the story ha

It's a confusing quote but it's saying "in the same manner as the walls of Jericho were brought down, so too did God humble the Persians by sending Heraclius against them." The author is telling us about the events at Jerusalem by way of drawing a parallel between them and the Biblical story of Jericho.

I'll refer straight to the Russian text which predates the English, and which in turn is a translation of the Georgian translation of the (lost to us) original Greek, because it'll be easier to translate Russian into English than archaic English into modern.
The omitted "pious ejaculations" are important for context here because the previous paragraph says:

Ибо все это произошло от Господа, чтобы научить согрешивших и счистить яд их грехов множеством бедствий.


This all came from God, to teach sinners and cleanse the poison of their sins through many troubles.

The paragraph goes on in this fashion.
Then the paragraph you quote begins:

И Иерусалим страдал сначала от египтян, но затем, когда признал Бог нужным их гибель, колесницы и кони их пали и доспехи их вооруженных потонули. Таким же образом вмиг разрушились Иерихонские стены, когда угодно было Богу повергнуть их, и унизил Благий царем Ираклием также множество персов, когда Он взглянул на Свой народ с милостью.


And Jerusalem suffered first from the Egyptians, but when God decided that they had to perish, their chariots and horses fell, and their warriors' armor sank. In the same way, the walls of Jericho were instantly destroyed when it was suitable to God that they should fall, and so did the All-good use King Heraclius to humble many Persians as soon as he, once more, looked upon his people with mercy.

In other words, this is a sermon. Strategius is contextualizing the (historical) sack of Jerusalem with similar (Biblical) events. His point is that all these events delivered just enough punishment on the faithful for the sins they committed, but no more than that, and once the role of the punishing force was done, God's will saw it destroyed in turn.
The sermon continues from the perspective of the monks captured by the Persians from the surroundings of Jerusalem who were apparently led to the city by the invading army, and the various visions they saw of angels and so forth.

Doen't this  end with the murder of every Christian in the city? Hard to qualify that as tough love.

From the wiki article on this siege: According to Sebeos the siege resulted in a total Christian death toll of 17,000

I think Strategius would respond that the magnitude of the punishment matched the magnitude of the sin. The salient point is that the context answers @AbhishekYadav's question.
